# How to find and replace strings containing invalid HTML tags to valid tags

Tags: c#

I have a string containing a list of html tags with invalid tag formatting.

For example, I have a string such as that below:

```
<p>
  <strong>Scale:</strong>
</p>
<p>
  <ul style="list-style-type:disc" class="pl-2">

  <li>2 to 4 nodes</li>
  </ul>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Single Node Data:</strong>
</p>
<p>
  <ul style="list-style-type:disc" class="pl-2">
  <li>CPU: 6-26 cores (Intel)</li> 
  <li>RAM: 128GB to 2TB</li>
  <li>Raw storage: 240GB to 16TB</li>
  <li>Storage type: SSD + HDD</li>
  <li>Network speed: Up to 25Gb</li>
  </ul>
</p><img src="xxxxx"/>
```

I need to replace the tags ending with `/>` to `</img>`, such that `<img src="xxxxx"/>` would be replaced with `<img src="xxxxx"></img>`.

How would I achieve this using C#?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow....What your tried so far? What is your input and what is expected output?

Comment: That is not an invalid tag

Answer (score 0):

For what you are asking, you can go with either one of the following options

**Option 1**

You can use a 3rd party library that parses your HTML into tags (it actually renders it as XML) and separate each tag (and its content) in a string array/list

then you loop the list and check if the closing tag is proper, if not replace it with the proper one.

Here is the [library](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

**Option 2**

You can create your own html parser, which would give you more control over the parser's logic, i found this example of C# HTML parser on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57176/Parsing-HTML-Tags-in-Cand) you can check it out.